# Call a javascript function inside of Jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, tigra-calendar

I am using the code below to append a row to my table, it works perfectly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tr_clone_add").click(function(){
        $('#listuser > tbody').after(
            '<tr><td><input type="text" class="tcal" readonly="true" path="date_debut"/></td></tr>'
          );
    });
});
```

I am using [Tigra Calendar](http://www.softcomplex.com/products/tigra_calendar/) and following the instruction have given the input `class="tcal"` so it should display the calendar/datepicker. However the calendar does not appear and I get just the simple input field. How can I get the calendar to display?

This is how I call the calendar:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tcal.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="tcal.js"></script>
```

Comment: **Almost** readable& understandable. use `on`, I believe this is the issue.

Comment: So do I... Your sentences seem to be taken from Google translate or something similar.

Comment: do you mean jquery ui's datepicker? if so put this `$(".tcal").datepicker();` at the beginning of `.ready()`

Comment: Show us where you bind the `tcal` code. I have a feeling you are doing a static bind, and not delegating for dynamic elements

Comment: I didn't use google !!! i just write my question quickly

Comment: I use [this](http://www.softcomplex.com/products/tigra_calendar/) calendar  I just include the js file and the css file and it can work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using Tigra Calendar http://www.softcomplex.com/products/tigra_calendar/

Firstly, the reason why this isn't working is because this calendar library expects the page to have completely loaded and no other elements are to be added to the page after it is initially loaded.

Secondly, you can fix it by calling the `f_tcalInit()` to initialize the calendar again after you add elements. Like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tr_clone_add").click(function(){
        $('#listuser > tbody').after('<tr><td><input type="text" class="tcal" readonly="true" path="date_debut"/></td></tr>');
        f_tcalInit();
    });
});
```